# Laravelbook/Ardent ignoring autoHydrateEntityFromInput value

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ardent

I have `$autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true` and `$forceEntityHydrationFromInput = false` because I want the input elements not in the model rules to be dropped during hydration. If they aren't dropped, there is a "column not found" error for the model on update because some of the form fields are supplemental.

However, when these two settings are used in this way, Ardent will not update any of the fields. It will only update fields when `$forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true`, which does not appear to be the functionality described in the documentation.

Am I wrong? If so, how do I get the fields auto-hydrated while excluding any not found in the rules?

I can use `Ardent::$purgeFilters` to specifically exclude each supplemental field that isn't in the model, but that seems like it should be unnecessary given the documented functionality for auto-hydration.